# Syntax error: "done" unexpected when trying to run shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The code

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
  mpc current > current_song.txt
  mpc idle player
done
```

is resulting in

```
Syntax error: "done" unexpected
```

Any reason why it would be showing done as unexpected?

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) doesn't find any issues with the script and neither do I. Is this snippet exactly what you ran? If so, maybe try running `cat -A` on the script to see if there are any non-printing characters messing it up (e.g. a carriage return after `do`) .

Comment: This works just fine when testing locally. (I replaced the `mpc` commands with `echo mpc`.  What exactly are the `mpc` commands doing?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You're missing the brackets on the condition.

```
#!/bin/sh
while [ true ]
do
  mpc current > current_song.txt
  mpc idle player
done
```

Comment: `true` is a command that returns true (0). The brackets are not necessary; they actually make it so that you're testing if the string `"true"` is non-zero.

Comment: @wjandrea - the brackets are necessary in bourne shell to prevent the syntax error presented in the OP's question.  In *bash* shell they are not necessary.  The OP is not using bash.

Comment: No. Try it for yourself. Also try `while [ false ] ...` and you'll notice that it behaves the same as `while [ true ] ...`.

Comment: @wjandrea - hmm, yeah you're right.  My test had a typo.